# Is it possible to have transition between switching base layers

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I use OpenLayers to display several maps. While transitioning between Google Map layers, the new layer is superimposed onto the old one. But for OpenStreetMaps, there is this empty void in between transitions. Is there a setting for making individual tiles of the old layer stay until the tiles of the new layer are available?

Comment: Something similar to the resize effect